# jquery. Regarding xhr.open get warning "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."

Tags: jquery

There are multiple similar questions, but from answers can not understand why such warning.

I use `jquery-1.11.2.js`

On page load no such warning.

Waring is after i click on link, and with `$.post` load content from external php file.

Warning is this `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.`

[image]

Tried to delete `options.async` from `jquery-1.11.2.js`. No changes

Tried to comment the line. jquery does not work.

Any ideas why the warning. I also use `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js`. But if remove it, see the same warning.

**Update**
Once i got solution in following way:

Before i had`<script src="//'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

I changed to

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getScript( "http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/javascript/jquery-ui.js" )
.done(function( script, textStatus ) { //.... do what necessary
```

example from here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

In result jquery loads only after whole document loaded....

Comment: I'm having the same problem, haven't found any solutions yet. Anybody?

Comment: @GoonNguyen Updated my question with one solution. May try it